# Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 33266

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have created a security policy in my database. When I'm trying to create a index on a view it says

> The index on the view 'dbo.vwUserFullNames' cannot be created because the view is referencing table 'dbo.Persons' that is referenced by a security policy.

is it possible to create indexes on views with security policy?

**create view**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwUserFullNames] WITH SCHEMABINDING AS //select ...
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn765131):

> In general, security policies can be created on top of views, and
>   views can be created on top of tables that are bound by security
>   policies. However, indexed views cannot be created on top of tables
>   that have a security policy, because row lookups via the index would
>   bypass the policy.

A possible workaround would be to define the security policy on the view, but then your table can't use one (and so, if you have multiple views, you'd need to repeat the security policy on individual views).